# Method has incorrect signature

Tags: android-studio

Despite having the method onButtonHomeClick declared in the Java file MainActivity, when I attempt to reference the method in the XML I receive the error message: "Method onButtonHomeClick in MainActivity has incorrect signature". Both of them are below, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is returning such an error, especially since attempting to navigate to the declaration by Ctrl clicking onButtonHomeClick in the XML file navigates to the method in the Java class.
And it's definitely struggling to find the method, as the Android Monitor returns a fatal error when attempting to assign the behaviour to the button.

```
<!-- XML file -->
<item
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:onClick="onButtonHomeClick"
        app:showAsAction="always"
    />

//Java method
public void onButtonHomeClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Clean your project and then make sure the method onButtonHomeClick() is declared as `public void`.

Answer (score 2):

Your On Click Method has Invalid Arguments for `MenuItem`. For `MenuItem`, it is

```
public void onClickMethod(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Whereas `public void onClickMethod(View view) {...}` is for `View` present in your activity layout.

Also just creating an `Intent` will not start the `Activity`. For starting the activity you should pass your intent to `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `startActivity(intent);` in your method, so it should be something like this:

```
public void onButtonHomeClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I tried your code with `startActivity(intent);` included and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/mRecharge_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

in your activity create public fun onClick

```
  public fun onClick(view: View?) {
  // do ur logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also define the `android: onClick` method to all views. Remember that the click method name is the same in all views.

```xml
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:onClick="OnClickView"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton_discoun_percent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discoun Percent"
        android:onClick="OnClickView" />
</RadioGroup>
```

```java
public void OnClickView(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.radioButton_score:
            Toast.makeText(this, "click Score", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton_discoun_percent:
            Toast.makeText(this, "click Discoun Percent", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you remember to include in your MainActvity.java file the import for the View class? (It's not imported by default.)

```
import android.view.View;
```